# Distributing Access Forms to global users for validations or amendments

Tags: ms-access

Intent: I would like to distribute forms to User X, User Y and User Z. These forms would be pre-populated with existing data on their ongoing projects. Meaning for User X, he will only be able to see his own details etc. They are to validate the information, and make changes to the data if necessary.

I tried finding the best way to go about executing this and landed on MS Access (if there's something else, please do share).

So I have a database, created my forms but how do I go about sharing only the forms to my users and updating my database. Resources I have include:

1. SharePoint Online (may or may not have access to it...)
2. Outlook
3. Desktop Access

I am open to various scenarios involving direct updating through SharePoint, or even manually updating the forms received through them via email if it is possible.

My most important consideration is data security. User X should not be able to see the details of other users. User-level security from older versions of Access could probably do that but its no longer in the newer version and a check online suggests it isn't the most secure option.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: if the data security is most important than the best way to do link those table which is User x need. Use the same frond end and link those table which user Y need and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You do not include any information on what kind of data your "forms" includes why you collect the data and what do you want to do with it. At the very least if data from multiple users needs to be combined for any sort of overall reporting.

If the most important consideration is limiting each user to a sub-set of the data then I don't see how you decided MS Access is your best option. Any security on an Access file is easily bypassed. On top of that unless each of your users has their own set of tables you cannot set up any kind of security that isolates their individual information.

To completely isolate user information you have three options:

- Use a separate database for each. Then, if you need to, link them all
  into a master database in the back end.
- Use an isolated front end. You cannot use an Access front end as that
  will have to link to the tables; you have to use a separate
  interface, either a web type interface or a Windows application that
  the user has to log on and has no access to any data other than what
  the software is displaying.
- Use import/export files. Have access export each user's info to an
  Excel sheet or other convenient data file. Let them make their
  changes and return the files to you, then import them back into your
  database.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have many resources and (very) limited database knowledge. The data is a combination of text/numbers based on project details (e.g., number of employees, issues at a particular stage etc). The data, when presented to a user is for their validation based on what they have provided previously since this is done periodically (monthly). If there are no changes, that's it. If there are changes, they make the changes. All their inputs will be consolidated for the purpose of churning a report.

Comment: Hence, I chose Access because data is saved there and populated in the form ready for changes to be made. Correct me if I'm mistaken but am I looking for something with row-level security and this isn't available in Access? Any alternatives I should be looking at?

Comment: I don't know of any database system that has row level security on the back end. That kind of security is only possible when the users do not have direct access to the tables. The 3 options above are your only viable solutions with any database system, although the first one is not possible with server based databases only file based ones like Access.